# Nativescript UI Pro licence on CI

Tags: telerik, travis-ci, nativescript

I'm trying to enable Travis CI on my NativeScript project and have purchased a NativeScript UI Pro library (without support).

How can I enable the license on each build on the server?

When installing the package it is referenced to a local `.tgz` file. in `package.json` like this:

```
dependencies: {
  "nativescript-telerik-ui-pro": "file:pathToTelerikUiProPackage.tgz"
}
```

How can I make this file available to Travis without adding it to source control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further research made it clear that I needed to co-locate the Nativescript UI Pro package to my source code.
Given I work on an open source project this was not a solution.

As a work around I placed the package in a private repository and added a `before_install` script to download the file to the working directory on Travis.

`.travis.yml`:

```
before_install:
    - sh get-nativescript-ui-pro.sh
```

The script to download is as follows.

`get-nativescript-ui-pro.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$PRIVATE_USER" = "" ];
then
  echo "ERROR: Can't get nativescript-ui-pro package. User not set";
  exit;
fi

curl --trace /dev/null -s -O -u $PRIVATE_USER {LINK TO RESOURCE}
```

Replace `{LINK TO RESOURCE}` with a complete link to the resource, i.e. the stored Nativescript UI Pro `.tgz` file. An environment variable named `PRIVATE_USER` holds the credentials to the repository account. This can be set in the Travis configuration panel for the specific repository.

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the Pro install instructions at http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/getting-started

I don't have Pro, but it sounds like you don't use NPM to install it - you manually extract the file you get from their website and then add it as a plugin.

If this doesn't help, consider posting a question on their dedicated forums.

Comment: Maybe I was a bit unclear regarding `npm` and `tns`. I've followed the instructions, but I have no way of installing some binary on the Travis CI before running `tns install`